# python object changes the value of an input variable

Tags: python, arrays, object, numpy, numerical-integration

So I don't know if this is a well-formed question, and I'm sorry if it isn't, but I'm pretty stumped.  Furthermore, I don't know how to submit a minimal working example because I can't reproduce the behavior without the whole code, which is a little big for stackexchange.

So here's the problem: I have an object which takes as one of its arguments a numpy array.  (If it helps, this array represents the initial conditions for a differential equation which a method in my object solves numerically.)  After using this array to solve the differential equation, it outputs the answer just fine, BUT the original variable in which I had stored the array has now changed value.  Here is what I happens:

```
import numpy as np
import mycode as mc

input_arr = np.ndarray(some_shape)
foo = mc.MyClass(input_arr)
foo.numerical_solve()
some_output
```

Fine and dandy.  But then, when I check on `input_arr`, it's changed value.  Sometimes it's the same as `some_output` (which is to say, the final value of the numerical solution), but sometimes it's some interstitial step.

As I said, I'm totally stumped and any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: You need to show the code of your class and `numerical_solve`.  Presumably `numerical_solve` is mutating the array (e.g., by setting values in it).

Comment: There's no reason why `MyClass` or `numeric_solve` couldn't change the `input_arr` in place, and this is fairly common.  Sometimes, for example, this will be used to save time and/or space; for example, numpy's infix operator's (eg, x += 1) can be faster than making repeated copies of the array.  If you want to save the original, you can just make a copy, but *a priori* the change doesn't indicate a problem.

Comment: Why don't you use a copy?

Comment: `foo = mc.MyClass(np.copy(input_arr))` copies the array.

Comment: numpy.copy() will definitely solve the problem

Comment: Thanks! that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a mutable object (`list`, `set`, `numpy.array`, ...) and you do not want it mutated, then you need to make a copy and pass that instead:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = l1[:]

s1 = set([1, 2, 3])
s2 = s1.copy()

arr1 = np.ndarray(some_shape)
arr2 = np.copy(arr1)
```